# SPID of a SqlConnection (SQL-Server) in ADO.NET

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Can I get a **SPID** from a **SqlConnection Object** (SQL-Server Database) in **ADO.NET**?

Is the SPID always the same for a connection object during its lifetime ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`select @@SPID` gives you the spid.

It should be constant, but may be recycled if you have connection pooling.